# Substitute for e.range when using onChange()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I need to use onChange() for my script, but I dont know how to modify the function I had made for onEdit() for onChange(), specially because of some of the methods that I used. Here's how I start my code:

```
function onChange(e) {
  if(e.changeType == "EDIT" || e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW"){
    if (e.source.getSheetName() == "Sheet1" && range.getColumn() == 1) {
      var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
      var range = e.range;
      var startRow = e.range.getRow();
      var endRow = e.range.getLastRow();
```

I have absolutely no idea how to proceed

Comment: If you wish to see the entire event object then add `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));` to the second line and generate a trigger.   Look in executions after the next trigger.

Comment: There does not appear to be a range key  in the  onChange event object

Comment: There also is no e.source.  See this article for the [onChange event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Hi and welcome. You said "_I **need** to use onChange() for my script_". Would you please explain why you **need** to use `onChange`. In other words, edit your question to provide an explanation of your scenario; it might be that someone can offer a different solution.